# Basic linear algebra on spark matrices

Tags: python, matrix, apache-spark

I am trying to run some basic linear algebra operations (specifically transpose, dot product, and inverse) on a matrix stored as a spark RowMatrix as described here[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#rowmatrix) (using the Python API). Following the example in the docs (for my case I will have many more rows in the matrix, hence the need for Spark), suppose I have something like this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
# Create an RDD of vectors.
rows = sc.parallelize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
# Create a RowMatrix from an RDD of vectors.
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
```

Given such a distributed matrix, are there existing routines for doing matrix transpose and dot product, e.g:

```
dot(mat.T,mat)
```

or matrix inverse?

```
inverse(mat)
```

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about this. Looking for either (a) a pointer to the relevant docs or (b) a method for implementing this myself.

Comment: do you have to store your data as a spark RowMatrix?  doing things like you want is easy in pandas.

Comment: I guess I could have been clearer when I said "I will have many more rows in the matrix". This data is too big for memory (and therefore for pandas). If possible, I would just use straight numpy arrays and matrix operations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for now (Spark 1.6.0) `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed` API is limited to basic operations like counting rows/columns and transformations between types.

Scala API supports a broader set of methods including multiplication (`RowMatrix.multiply`, `Indexed.RowMatrix.multiply`), transposition,  SVD (`IndexedRowMatrix.computeSVD`), QR decomposition (`RowMatrix.tallSkinnyQR`), Grammian Matrix computation (`computeGramianMatrix`), PCA (`RowMatrix.computePrincipalComponents`) which can be used to implement more complex linear algebra functions.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do you know of any way to expose that functionality in the Python API, or is totally impossible?

Comment: Well, it is not impossible. `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed` is just a wrapper around Scala API, and most of the job is done through `self._java_matrix_wrapper.call`. Theoretically you can add your own methods but I am not sure if it is worth all the fuss.

Comment: well, I suppose we'd have to compare the relative fuss of reimplementing our model in scala vs. implementing these methods...

Comment: It is not the only option. For example if you have a long and skinny matrix you can easily implement some operations (like t(x) %*% t) using local vectors. SVD can be computed iteratively and it is a short way to get pseudoinverse. Finally it could make sense to write your algorithm in Scala and convert only input and output.

Comment: also, do you know specifically if the scala api supports matrix inverse?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't but you can use either QR or SVD to compute pseudoinverse. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 1.6 and later, you can do matrix arithmetic operations by means of the BlockMatrix class.  Only multiply and add are available in Spark 1.6.  In Spark 2.0, more are added.  As of this writing you would have to implement inverse by hand, but dot and transpose is available.  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/distributed.py#L811.  Here's a Spark 1.6 example.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix, BlockMatrix

sc = SparkContext()
rows = sc.parallelize([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]) \
    .zipWithIndex()

# need a SQLContext() to generate an IndexedRowMatrix from RDD
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
rows = IndexedRowMatrix( \
    rows \
    .map(lambda row: IndexedRow(row[1], row[0])) \
    ).toBlockMatrix()

mat_product = rows.multiply(<SOME OTHER BLOCK MATRIX>)
```