# Vector and Matrix classes for linear algebra in Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-algebra

Does Spark 2.4 have Vector and Matrix classes that support basic linear algebra operations like dot product, norm, matrix and vector multiplication?  I can't find any linear algebra support in classes like Vector, DenseVector, or RowMatrix.

Older versions of Spark had org.jblas.DoubleMatrix, but that doesn't exist in Spark 2.4 and I can't find what they replaced it with.

Where do I look for linear algebra examples in spark 2.4?

I don't need RDDs for my current need (cosine similarity).

Comment: You can use breeze and it's numeric library which work on vectors/matrices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic linear algebra on spark matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704333/basic-linear-algebra-on-spark-matrices)

Comment: The link to Basic linear algebra... is for version 1.6 using Python.  So this is not a  duplicate of that post.